# change of address tool in new google console

Tags: google-search-console

we are changing our primary domain in google webmaster new console.
But when we search change domain it redirected to old console.
But console doesn't work.[image: shot from console]
we add and verify domain and url but console can not find our domain.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!